# Read in Python code/regular expressions from external file

Tags: python

I have a section of Python (Sigil) code:

```
  for (id, href) in bk.text_iter():
    html = bk.readfile(id)
    html = re.sub(r'<title></title>', '<title>Mara’s Tale</title>', html)
    html = re.sub(r'<p>Mara’s Tale</p>', '<p class="title">Mara’s Tale</p>',html)
  bk.writefile(id, html)
```

Ideally, I'd like to read the regular expressions in from an external text-file (or just read in that block of code). Any suggestions? I've done similar in Perl with a *try*, but I'm a Python-novice.

Also, quick supplementary question - shouldn't *bk.writefile* be indented? And, if so, why is my code working? It looks as though it's outside the *for* block, and therefore will only write to the final file, if that (it's an epub, so there are several html files), but it's updating all relevant files.

Regarding *bk*, my understanding is that this object is the whole epub, and what this code is doing is reading each html file that makes up an epub via text_iter, so *id* is each individual file.

EDIT TO ADD

Ah! That bk.writefile should indeed be indented. I got away with it because, at the point I run this code, I only have a single html file.

Comment: hard to help with this while `bk` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the reading something from a file - it's easy. Assume you have the file 'my_file.txt' in the same folder where the script is saved:

```
f =  open('my_file.txt', 'r')

content = f.read()              # read all content of the file in the sting 'content'
lines   = f.read().splitlines() # read lines of the file in array 'lines'

f.close()

print(lines[0]) # first line
print(lines[1]) # second line
# etc
```

As for shouldn't `bk.writefile` be indented? Yep, it seems the loop makes and changes the variable `html` for several times but saves only the last iteration. It looks weird. Perhaps it should be indented. But it's just a guess.

Comment: That's fine for printing the lines, but what about executing them? (or treating them as variables to a regex loop?)

Comment: `my_regex1 = lines[0]` , `my_regex2 = lines[1]` and so on. `html = re.sub(my_regex1, my_regex2, html)` . But it's need to test, probably some symbols like `\\` need a special treatment.

Comment: And probably it makes sense to use JSON format instead the plain TXT to save and load variables.